# SQL integration of two queries

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x

Previously, I stored age as an integer calculated from a customers DOB using an sql query in a database. However, after realising this was bad practice, I am trying to produce a query which calculates the age from the users DOB, and selects the number of orders per age group per month. But instead, age is not stored as a value in the database, but rather calculated

I have this query which does just this, but assumes age is already a value calculated in the database, and thus utilises it:

```
    #Query1
    select COUNT(orderid) as OrderCount,
    DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%m-%Y") as month
    FROM customerOrders
    INNER JOIN customerDetails ON
    customerDetails.customerid=customerOrders.customerid
    WHERE customerDetails.age BETWEEN 17 AND 24
    group by month
    order by strftime("%Y", orderDate)
```

And i have this query which calculates the age from a customers DB:
       #Query2

```
   SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) - DOB - 1
   FROM customerDetails
```

PseudoCode implementation:

```
    select COUNT(orderid) as OrderCount,
    DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%m-%Y") as month,
    age = (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) - DOB - 1 as age
    FROM customerOrders, customerDetails
    INNER JOIN customerDetails ON
    customerDetails.customerid=customerOrders.customerid

    WHERE 
    age BETWEEN 17 AND 24

    FROM customerDetails
    group by month
    order by strftime("%Y", orderDate
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the age, how about just using an `update` with `timestampdiff()`:

```
update customerDetails
    set age = timestampdiff(dob, curdate());
```

That said, storing age in a table is a REALLY bad idea.  It literally changes every day.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ad some aliases and subquery. Example pseudocode below.

```
select * 
from 
(
    select COUNT(orderid) as OrderCount,
    DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%m-%Y") as month,
    (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) - DOB - 1
    FROM customerDetails cd1
    WHERE cd1.customerid = cd.customerid
    ) as age
    FROM customerOrders co, customerDetails cd
    INNER JOIN customerDetails ON
    cd.customerid=co.customerid
) A

where age > 17 and age < 24
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want integrate age calculation into existing query just do it:

```
select COUNT(orderid) as OrderCount,
    DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%m-%Y") as month,
    (YEAR(CURDATE()) - DOB - 1) as age
FROM customerOrders
INNER JOIN customerDetails ON
    customerDetails.customerid=customerOrders.customerid
WHERE (YEAR(CURDATE()) - DOB - 1) BETWEEN 17 AND 24
GROUP BY month, (YEAR(CURDATE()) - DOB - 1)
ORDER BY strftime("%Y", orderDate);
```